# How to convert Pandas Dataframe to Nested Json Output

Tags: arrays, json, pandas, nested, python-3.6

I am new to converting pandas DataFrames to JSON format.

I have input as a DataFrame:

```
a1       a2      a3      a4  a5
agent1   abc     quote1  NJ  19029
agent1   abc     quote1  NJ  19029
agent2   xyz     quote2  CA  95003
agent2   xyz     quote2  CA  95003
```

Here each row represents the quote line for each agent. The duplication of rows is intentional.

I am looking for the output as below in JSON format:

```
{
        "quotes": [
            {
                "agents": [
                    {
                        "a1": "agent1",
                        "a2": "abc",
                        "a3": "quote1",
                        "a4": "NJ",
                        "a5": "19029"
                    },
                    {
                        "a1": "agent1",
                        "a2": "abc",
                        "a3": "quote1",
                        "a4": "NJ",
                        "a5": "19029"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "agents": [
                    {
                        "a1": "agent2",
                        "a2": "xyz",
                        "a3": "quote2",
                        "a4": "CA",
                        "a5": "95003"
                    },
                    {
                      "a1": "agent2",
                        "a2": "xyz",
                        "a3": "quote2",
                        "a4": "CA",
                        "a5": "95003"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]}
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you have formatted your output is not one that's supported directly by Pandas [to_json](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html) output. It requires some restructuring of the DataFrame:

```
# Create dictionaries of the records for the groups of quotes and agents
grouped = df.groupby(["a3", "a1"]).apply(lambda x: x.to_dict(orient="records"))

# Build the final dictionary:
quotes_dict = {"quotes": [{"agents": x} for x in grouped]}

# Create json
json.dumps(quotes_dict, indent=4)
```

Creates this output:

```
{
    "quotes": [
        {
            "agents": [
                {
                    "a1": "agent1",
                    "a2": "abc",
                    "a3": "quote1",
                    "a4": "NJ",
                    "a5": 19029
                },
                {
                    "a1": "agent1",
                    "a2": "abc",
                    "a3": "quote1",
                    "a4": "NJ",
                    "a5": 19029
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "agents": [
                {
                    "a1": "agent2",
                    "a2": "xyz",
                    "a3": "quote2",
                    "a4": "CA",
                    "a5": 95003
                },
                {
                    "a1": "agent2",
                    "a2": "xyz",
                    "a3": "quote2",
                    "a4": "CA",
                    "a5": 95003
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```